# Vim reflow paragraph adds unwanted indentation

Tags: vim

When I use `gqap' command to reflow a paragraph in vim, vim seems to try to be smart and adds indentation automatically, e.g.

- When a line ends with a ',':

```
We protect your rights with two steps: (1) copyright the software, and (2),
   offer you this license which gives you legal permission to copy, distribute
   and/or modify the software.
```

- When a line has unmatched brackets:

```
Program or a portion of it, either verbatim or with modifications and/or
translated into another language. (Hereinafter, translation is included without
        limitation in the term "modification".) Each licensee is addressed as
"you".
```

Is there a way to turn this off?

Thanks!

Comment: I use now `gwap` which also restores the cursor position!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What filetype do you do this in? And what is the output of ':set'?

If you copy your texts to an empty file, it formats it the way you want it. I have smartindent and autoindent enabled, so you could try that. (set si, set ai)

Answer (score 1):

I notice I have cindent set.. Unset that and instead set smartindent and autoindent and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: smartindent and autoindent had no influence on this, but cindent did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem too, but unlike the other answers suggest, it was occurring in a .txt file without cindent set. However, I noticed that smartindent **was** set, and disabling this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I looked at my settings like this:

:set

I didn't have cindent set, but I did have smartindent. So, based on the above:

:set nosmartindent

Then the unwanted indentation on the last line (just as described above) was fixed.

Thanks for the help!